# Aggregation with in list of objects in document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

First of all i am explain my scenario as below.

I have documents with below format.

Suppose document name is "ABC" and document format is

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
  "name" : "....",
  "datalist" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-01T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : 20
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-08T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -310
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-11-17T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : 197
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-10-06T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -126
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-20T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -344
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-15T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -98
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-03-01T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -254
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-02-11T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -24
    },
  ]
}
```

I have to find the avg of each index of "datalist" from same date to before 3, 6 and 12 months dates with in list and put it back with the same index of object in "datalist"

so my output should be

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
  "datalist" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-01T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : 20,
        "threeMonthAvg": -54.75,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -110.167,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -117.375
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-08T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -310,
        "threeMonthAvg": -79.67,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -136.2,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -137
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-11-17T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : 197,
        "threeMonthAvg": 35.5,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -92.75,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -108.167
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-10-06T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -126,
        "threeMonthAvg": -189.33,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -189.33,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -169.2
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-20T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -344,
        "threeMonthAvg": -221,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -180,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -180
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-15T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -98,
        "threeMonthAvg": -98,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -125.33,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -125.33
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-03-01T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -254,
        "threeMonthAvg": -139,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -139,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -139
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-02-11T18:30:00Z"),
        "data" : -24,
        "threeMonthAvg": -79.6666666667,
        "sixMonthAvg" : -24,
        "twelveMothAvg" : -24
    },
  ]
}
```

I am trying as bellow now.

```
 db.ABC.aggregate([
    {
        $match : { "id" : ...}
    },
    { 
       $unwind : "$datalist"
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$id",
            datalist : {
                $push :{
                    date : "$datalist.date",
                    data : "$datalist.data",
                    rollingAvgThreeMonth : {
                        $avg : { 
                            $and: [
                                { $gte: [ "$datalist.date", new Date("$datalist.date") ] }, 
                                { $lte: [ "$datalist.date", new Date().setDate( new Date("$datalist.date").getMonth() - 3) ]}
                            ]
                        }                            
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @Veeram Actually as per my logic i stuck in aggregation. my logic is as below.

1st i need to unwind "datalist" from document,
2nd Group with id and find avg with cond, Like suppose i am at first index  then i need calculate before date from current index date and then add to set again with the same index.

I don't know its a correct or not , But now i am trying to do like above.

Comment: @Veeram Is it possible to use another aggregation function with in $group?

Comment: Please add to the post your incomplete solution.

Comment: @Veeram Hi, Thanks to give interest. I updated my question. i added my current aggregation which return null in  " rollingAvgThreeMonth ". "rollingAvgThreeMonth" is just only for demo.